# subir base de datos a hostinger

Tags: json, nodejs, express, hosting, backend

estoy intentando realizar una base de datos con node js express y mysql. tengo una estructura de datos json que se encarga de rellenar mi pagina de productos y administra el proceso de mi carrito de compras.

```
"dataProduct":
        [
            {      
                "id" : 1,
                "cat": "mates",
                "name" : "Mate 1",
                "img" : "img/EquipoMateroNegroT.png",
                "price" : 999,
                "cantidad": 1,
                "descripcion": "verde",
                "longDesc": "ESTA SERIA LA DESCRIPCION"
            },
```

Me están surgiendo dudas con respecto a mysql, ya que recién arranco con back end, quería saber como podría subir lo que yo arme a mi hosting en hostinger, para que este activo 24/7 y el dueño de la pagina web pueda administrar la actualización de los datos mediante un crud bastante amigable. gracias

Comment: Quieres que te lo hagamos? O que problema tienes?

Comment: tengo la api administrable armada con node expres y mysql, la duda que tengo es como hacer que eso se pueda utilizar 24/7 online, mi logica dice que se deberia subir al hosting la cosa es que no se como subir una base de datos a un hosting, quisiera saber si hay algun video que explique como, o si me pueden dar una mano, quiero saber hacerlo no que me lo hagan

Comment: para que tu api funcione 24/7 basta con que este en un hosting (que te proporcione el servicio 24/7), en cuanto a al BD los hosting tienen una opcion para crear tu BD, practicamente es igual que trabajar en local